# Implement the Fibonacci-quine

Tags: code-golf, sequence, quine, fibonacci

A [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) is a program which outputs its source when run.

In this challenge, You should make a Fibonacci-quine, a variant of the quine.

---

### What is a Fibonacci-quine?

A Fibonacci-quine is a program, which outputs a modification of the source by the following rule:

The initial source should be `...2...`. In other words, the source should contain `2`. (Why 2? If it was 1, Nobody would know if it was the first 1 or the second, Even the program itself)

When run, You should output the source, but *only* the specific number (In this stage, `2`) changed to the next number of the fibonacci sequence. For example, `...3...`. Same goes for the output, and the output of the output, etc. You may support integers for up to 2^32-1. For integers over that limit, the next output is on your choice.

> #### OP's note
>
> I would really like to see a creative solution for this. I couldn't think of a single solution for this, since Both of the two important aspects of the challenge, fibonacci and quine, is not easy. I'll be waiting then!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107642/48934).

Comment: The quine part doesn't add much to this challenge. This is just "next value in Fibonacci sequence" plus a universal quine constructors, as the answers show.

Comment: I agree. I would like to see a creative solution for this as well. But if you want a creative solution so bad, then why not make it a code-challenge instead of code-golf. The winning criteria could be the highest number of votes after some time interval or something.

Comment: @FixedPoint What about a 'Second criteria'? Someone makes a creative solution, I give them bounty.

Comment: @FixedPoint That's a [tag:popularity-contest]

Answer (score 8):

### Mathematica, 61 bytes

```
ToString[#0 /. v:2 :> RuleCondition[Round[GoldenRatio v]]] &
```

Note that there is a trailing space. This is a function quine, i.e. the above code evaluates to an unnamed function which, if called returns the code itself as a string (with `2` changed to the next Fibonacci number).

This was suprisingly tricky to get to work. The basic idea is to take the function itself (with `#0`) and replace a number in that function with the next one using `/. v:2 :> nextFib[v]`. However, `nextFib` wouldn't get evaluated at this stage so we wouldn't really end up with the new number in the source code. After searching around for a while to figure out how to force immediate evaluation, I found [this great post on Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/2305). The "standard" technique uses a `With` block which forces evaluation, but the second answer by WReach contains a shorter alternative using the undocumented built-in `RuleCondition` which also forces evaluation.

The way we compute the next Fibonacci number is by making use of the fact that the ratio of consecutive numbers is roughly the golden ratio **1.618...** and this is accurate up to rounding. So we don't need to keep track of the last two numbers and can simply do `Round[GoldenRatio v]`. This will never lose precision since Mathematica's `GoldenRation` is a symbolic value and therefore `Round` can always compute an accurate result.

In summary:

```
... #0 ... &
```

An unnamed function, where `#0` refers to the function object itself.

```
... /. v:2 :> ...
```

Find a `2` in the expression tree of the function (this `2` of course only matches itself), call it `v` and replace it with...

```
... RuleCondition[Round[GoldenRatio v]]
```

... the next Fibonacci number.

```
ToString[...]
```

And convert the resulting expression tree to its string representation.

Comment: It's nice to know you have to work hard at these sometimes :)

Comment: Isn't there a symbol for the golden ratio?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing no.

Answer (score 7):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 26 bytes

```
2{0X{_@+_W$>!}go;\;"_~"}_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@29UbRBRHe@gHR@uYqdYm55vHWOtFF@nVBtf9/8/AA)

Probably not quite optimal. We simply iterate the Fibonacci sequence until the value is greater than the last one and use the result as the new value at the beginning of the program.

Comment: Thi..This early?

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 95 bytes

```python
a=b=1
while a<2:a,b=b,a+b
s='a=b=1\nwhile a<%i:a,b=b,a+b\ns=%r;print(s%%(b,s))';print(s%(b,s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59om2RryFWekZmTqpBoY2SVqJNkm6STqJ3EVWyrDpaMyYPJqmYipGPyim1Vi6wLijLzSjSKVVU1knSKNTXV4QIQPtf//wA)

Obviously a fork of [Martin Ender's CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119544/48934).

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 20 bytes

```
2{\5mq)*)Y/io"_~"}_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@29UHWOaW6ippRmpn5mvFF@nVBtf9/8/AA)

Comment: Wow, 20 bytes: I'm speechless...

Answer (score 5):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 19 bytes

```
2⌠è@fuF$+";ƒ"@+⌡;ƒ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@2/0qGfB4RUOaaVuKtpK1scmKTloP@pZCGRw/f8PAA)

Obviously a fork of [Martin Ender's CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119544/48934).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>81</s> 79 bytes

```python
s='s=%r;print(s%%(s,round(%s*(1+5**.5)/2)))';print(s%(s,round(2*(1+5**.5)/2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19sq15sq1pkXVCUmVeiUayqqlGsU5RfmpeioVqspWGobaqlpWeqqW@kqampDlcEV2OEpoTr/38A)
Uses the golden ratio to calculate the next number

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
“×Øp+.ḞṭØv”Ṙv2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AR4A4f//4oCcw5fDmHArLuG4nuG5rcOYduKAneG5mHYy//8) or [verify all required iterations](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@SmqqQlpmUX1iamZeql5Wak1PJxZWWX6QQr5CZp1BtoqdnYllrrZCSz8WZmpwBJPXzC0r0weogpEJaKboBCnYKJam5BVycuWVgBoYFnMmJJRiCKfl5qf//P2qYc3j64RkF2noPd8x7uHPt4RlljxrmPtw5o8wIAA).

#### How it works

```
“×Øp+.ḞṭØv”Ṙv2  Main link. No arguments.

“×Øp+.ḞṭØv”     Set the left argument and return value to the string "×Øp+.ḞṭØv".
           Ṙ    Print a string representation of the return value and yield the
                unaltered return value.
            v2  Evaluate the return value as a Jelly program with left argument 2.
 ×Øp                Multiply the left argument by the golden ratio.
    +.              Add 0.5 to the resulting product.
      Ḟ             Floor; round the resulting sum down to the nearest integer.
        Øv          Yield the string "Øv".
       ṭ            Tack; append the result to the left to the result to the right.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 251 bytes

A bit verbose for me, but I can't figure out how to get it shorter:

```
import Foundation;var n="\"";var u="\\";var s="import Foundation;var n=%@%@%@%@;var u=%@%@%@%@;var s=%@%@%@;print(String(format:s,n,u,n,n,n,u,u,n,n,s,n,(round(%f*(1+sqrt(5))/2))))";print(String(format:s,n,u,n,n,n,u,u,n,n,s,n,(round(2*(1+sqrt(5))/2))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
import Foundation
var n="\""
var u="\\"
var s="import Foundation;var n=%@%@%@%@;var u=%@%@%@%@;var s=%@%@%@;print(String(format:s,n,u,n,n,n,u,u,n,n,s,n,(round(%f*(1+sqrt(5))/2))))"
print(String(format:s,n,u,n,n,n,u,u,n,n,s,n,(round(2*(1+sqrt(5))/2))))
```

My trouble is trying to get the quotes around the new version of `s`.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), <strike>151</strike> 60 bytes

New version, credits to @[Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun)

```
x=i=>console.log('x='+x+';x('+(i*(5**.5+1)/2+.5|0)+')');x(2)
```

Old version :

```
x=i=>{var s=Math.sqrt(5),a=1;f=n=>{return Math.ceil((((1+s)/2)**n-((1-s)/2)**n)/s)};while(f(++a)<=i);console.log('x='+String(x)+';x('+f(a)+')');};x(2)
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19892721/6882070).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! We hope that you will have a great time here.

Comment: @LeakyNun Hopefully fixed now !

Comment: Golfed version: `x=i=>console.log('x='+x+';x('+(i*(5**.5+1)/2+.5|0)+')');x(2)`

Comment: @LeakyNun wow, that's short ! But isn't it too approximate ? it outputs 50159 for i = 31000 although the right answer should be 46368

Comment: I don't understand. `31000` isn't a Fibonacci number.

Comment: @LeakyNun Yep, i think I misunderstood the question. I thought you needed to output the next Fibonnaci number greater than the input, whether the input is one or not.

Comment: So you can use my suggestion now \o/

Answer (score 1):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 136 bytes

```
let b=1;for(let a=1;a<2;a=b-a){b+=a};let s='let b=1;for(let a=1;a<%i;a=b-a){b+=a};let s=%s;print s%b%@"39+s+@"39';print s%b%@"39+s+@"39
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cheddar#@5@TWqKQZGtonZZfpAFiJwLZiTZG1om2SbqJmtVJ2raJtdYgiWJbdexqVTOxKVYtti4oyswDMlWTVB2UjC21i7VBlDp2Ya7//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](http://enwp.org/dc_(computer_program)), 35 bytes

```
2[r9k5v1+2/*.5+0k1/n91PP93P[dx]P]dx
```

A version with iteration (56 bytes):

```
2[rsP1dsN[lN+lNrsNdlP[s.q]s.=.lFx]dsFxlNn91PP93P[dx]P]dx
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 235 bytes

This is an improved version of [Caleb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68374/caleb-kleveter)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119576/13940).

```
import Foundation;var n="\"",u="\\",s="import Foundation;var n=%@%@%@%@,u=%@%@%@%@,s=%@%@%@;print(String(format:s,n,u,n,n,n,u,u,n,n,s,n,(round(%f*(1+sqrt(5))/2))))";print(String(format:s,n,u,n,n,n,u,u,n,n,s,n,(round(2*(1+sqrt(5))/2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 239 bytes

```java
interface a{static void main(String[]p){int a=1,b=1;for(;a<2;a=b-a)b+=a;String s="interface a{static void main(String[]p){int a=1,b=1;for(;a<%d;a=b-a)b+=a;String s=%c%s%c;System.out.printf(s,b,34,s,34);}}";System.out.printf(s,b,34,s,34);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#pcyxCsMgFIXhV5GAoNQG0nazPkXG0uFqtDhEg/emUEKe3QpdCx26nOV8/DUm8iWA8ww2JKDo2DPHic0QkxipxPS43Re5NcfADMqaQYdchIbrSYOxR5D2YEB/KEPT/VHk09ckdxy50@MLyc99Xqlf2kNBoLLqfFHYRup9736TWt8)